# How to determine what application consumes my available Internet traffic volume

Tags: windows-xp, internet, network-traffic

I'm wondering how I could check which services are consuming my Internet traffic as I've noticed that 100 MB of data is used within a few minutes?

The only websites I visit are Gmail, Facebook and Ebay. So I'm not sure what's using the data so fast. I'm running an up to date Firefox with no extensions on Windows XP.

Comment: [There probably is](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=bandwidth+monitor+xp).

Comment: Try Network Traffic Monitoring Tool  by Microsoft

Comment: I rephrased your question so it fits the SU concept. Don't ask for software recommendations. Rather you should ask "How to achieve this goal"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem

The main problem is, that most traffic monitoring tools only report the usage per network interface (WLAN / LAN / UMTS) - but not per application. But that's necessary if you want to identify the consuming application.

The second type of monitoring tools only show send/received bytes for active connections. As soon as a connection drops or the program is terminated, the consumed traffic isn't shown anymore and the tool gets useless.

#### Application comparison

I compared some popular tools to find one that combines the benefits of both worlds. The winner was Nirsofts [NetworkTrafficView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_traffic_view.html) together with [WinPcap driver](http://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm). It was the only one which summed up send/received bytes from all connections per application.

> [NetworkTrafficView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_traffic_view.html) is a network monitoring tool that captures the packets pass through your network adapter, and displays general statistics about your network traffic. The packets statistics is grouped by the Ethernet Type, IP Protocol, Source/Destination Addresses, and Source/Destination ports.

[image]

- You have to install WinPcap driver first
- Under Advanced options » General grouping » select *Group by process*
  That is the important option which all other tools lack.
  A small downside is, that UDP packets aren't counted, but that shouldn't affect the result as much.
- Hide all unnecessary columns like shown above in screenshot
- Sort by *Total packets size*

---

*What other tools I tried*

#### Sums up consumed traffic only per interface

- [NetMeter](http://www.metal-machine.de/readerror/)
- [Networx](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/)
- [NetSpeedMonitor](http://www.floriangilles.com/software/netspeedmonitor)
- [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) (alternative router firmware)

#### Sums up consumed traffic only for active connections

- [TCPview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx)
- [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html)
- Windows 7/8 build-in Resource Monitor

#### Untested

- [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (Can do everything, if you know how. Not user-friendly enough for your purpose I guess)
- [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) (Not tested, since no portable version available)
- [DU Meter](http://www.hageltech.com/dumeter/about) (no freeware)